# Nginx/FastCGI Mono performance problems

Tags: c#, nginx, mono, fastcgi

Does anybody have a solution on increasing performance of Nginx/FastCGI running Web API C# code?

My sample is extremely simple, but its fails with 50 concurrent users.
The server simply stuck with not processing any requests...

In the configuration i was thinking to set nginx to process up to 500 concurrent requests, where fastcgi would be started with maximum of 10000 connections and requests and therefore nginx would work as filter having onhold requests for fastcgi to have enought time to process current request.

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 1;
events{
    worker_connections 500;
}
```

sites_available/default

```
server {
 listen   80;
 server_name    192.168.163.138;
 access_log     /var/log/nginx/domain1.xyz.access.log;
 location ~ / {
        root    /var/www/www.domain1.xyz/;
        index index.html index.htm default.aspx Default.aspx;
        fastcgi_index default.aspx;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
 }
}
```

Command i use to start fastcgi:

> sudo fastcgi-mono-server4 /applications=192.168.163.138:/:/var/www/www.domain1.xyz/ /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000 /verbose=True /showlog=True /loglevels=Debug /maxconns=10000  /maxreqs=10000 /multiplex=false

I used siege to benchmark:

> sudo siege -t1M -c50 http://192.168.163.138/mono/test

Machine is VM with 1 core/1Gb RAM Ubuntu Server 14.4

If i give more resources to VM it start to work, but it does not look to be ok for me. Server shouldn't just hang, but still respond with some delay.
Any idea? Was anybody able to have it running with no problems like this...

Comment: A multithreaded application runs on a single core machine. Do you think that's even a valid test setup?

Comment: It is valid to be tested. Im not expecting ultra performance in this, but it should not stop responding. I can give there 2 cores, but i cant expect to have it 1 user per core. What is valid configuration should be?

Comment: my guess is that it hangs because there's some race condition that is only reproducible under high load, which makes the .NET pipeline throw some exception that is being swallowed somewhere, maybe you can run mono with `--trace` and redirect all exceptions to a log file, and start investigating from there